# How to define interdependent type Props for component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a few simplifications to my React-Typescript project, but I'm getting stuck on how to properly annotate types. Here's a stripped-down example of the code I'm working with:

https://codesandbox.io/s/working-example-qc5cq

```
// WORKING EXAMPLE
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const handleClick = (value: string | number): void => {
    if (typeof value === "string") {
      // Do some string logic...
      console.log(`String: ${value}`);
    } else if (typeof value === "number") {
      // Do some number logic
      console.log(`Number: ${value}`);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button handleClick={handleClick} value="Hello" />
      <Button handleClick={handleClick} value={42} />
    </div>
  );
};

interface Props {
  handleClick: (value: string | number) => void;
  value: string | number;
}
const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ handleClick, value }) => (
  <button onClick={(): void => handleClick(value)}>{value}</button>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

What I want to do is split the `handleClick`-function into two separate functions; one for dealing with `string`, one for dealing with `number`. The problem comes when I try to type `Props` for the `Button`-component. Here is where I'm at at the moment:

https://codesandbox.io/s/wip-example-fied2

```
// WIP
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const handleStringClick = (string: string) => {
    // Do some string logic...
    console.log(`String: ${string}`);
  };

  const handleNumberClick = (number: number): void => {
    // Do some number logic
    console.log(`Number: ${number}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button handleClick={handleStringClick} value="Hello" />
      <Button handleClick={handleNumberClick} value={42} />
    </div>
  );
};

interface StringProps {
  handleClick: (string: string) => void;
  value: string;
}
interface NumberProps {
  handleClick: (number: number) => void;
  value: number;
}
type Props = StringProps | NumberProps;
const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({ handleClick, value }) => (
  <button onClick={(): void => handleClick(value)}>{value}</button>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

The error I'm receiving is on `handleClick(value)`:

> Argument of type 'ReactText' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'never'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)

which is understandable since the type of `value` is interpreted as `string | number` (actually `ReactText`, but that's a React shorthand) and no version of `handleClick` handles that case.

---

So the question is, can I somehow annotate `Props` so that `handleClick` is dependant on the type of `value`? In other words, if I e.g. set `value` to a `number`, can I make Typescript understand and force me to pass in a `handleClick(number)`-function? Feel free to point me in better directions if my mind set or what I'm trying to achieve is a bit flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that is by making `Button` generic:

```
type Props<T extends string | number> = {
  handleClick: (argument: T) => void;
  value: T;
}
const Button= <T extends string | number,>({ handleClick, value }: Props<T>) => (
  <button onClick={(): void => handleClick(value)}>{value}</button>
);
```

```
<Button handleClick={arg => { /** `arg` is of type `42` */}} value={42} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Karol! I was able to tweak my code according to your suggestion; I left `Props` as you had and then extended your `Button`-code to have a return type:

```
const Button = <T extends string | number>({
  handleClick,
  value
}: Props<T>): JSX.Element => (
  <button onClick={(): void => handleClick(value)}>{value}</button>
);
```

Also found a great source on this: [Passing Generics to JSX Elements in TypeScript](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/passing-generics-to-jsx-elements-in-typescript)